# How to build a customized list in blackberry 6.0 that can be filtered?

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry development please provide a code snippet if you can?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Being code spoon-fed is not the best way to progress. Head to this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to foster your experience on `how to ask`on here.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/13094/Autocomplete_field_sample_app_overview_921362_11.jsp)

You can also check `keywordfilterdemo` sample app in samples in Blackberry JDE folder

Or you can try this bit of code

```
         Vector v = getElements();
         Enumeration iterator = v.elements();
        int i = 0;
        final Object[] objs = new Object[v.size()];
        while (iterator.hasMoreElements()) {
            objs[i] = (String) iterator.nextElement();
            i++;
        }
        BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        filterList.setMinimumRefreshInterval(250);
        filterList.addDataSet(1, objs, "names",
                BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(
                filterList, AutoCompleteField.LIST_STATIC) {

            public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g,
                    int index, int y, int width) {
                super.drawListRow(listField,g,index,y,width);
            }

            public void onSelect(Object selection, int type) {
                super.onSelect(selection, type);
                if (selection != null) {

                    BasicFilteredListResult result = (BasicFilteredListResult) this
                            .getSelectedObject();
                    handleResult((String) result._object);

                } else {
                    Dialog.alert("Please pick a valid element");
                    return;
                }
            }
        };

        screenFields.add(autoCompleteField);
```